# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when using NSRunAlertPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

To show errors on some condition, I am using NSRunAlertPanel on Mac OS X (on the code which is ported from Windows, where I was using MessageBox).

Before actual creation of Windows, some code is being run and calling this code to show some conditional error.

In a thread com.apple.libdispatch-manager, under following call stack

```
0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
1 _dispatch_mgr_thread
```

it is giving EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Is it because Windows is not created before NSRunAlertPanel?

What is the reason of this runtime error? What is exact alternative of MessageBox on Mac OS X?

```
Long ShowDebugMessageBox (const wchar_t * Message, const wchar_t * Title)
{
    NSString *  message;    ///< Message.
    NSString *  title;      ///< Title.
    NSInteger   response;   ///< response.

message     = WideToNSString (Message);
title       = WideToNSString (Title);


    //response    = NSRunAlertPanel(title, message, @"Yes", @"No", @"Cancel");
    response       = NSRunCriticalAlertPanel (title, message, @"Okay", @"Cancel", nil);

    switch(response) {
    case NSAlertDefaultReturn:
        return IDYES;
    case NSAlertAlternateReturn:
        return IDNO;

    default:
        return IDCANCEL;
    }

}


NSString *  WideToNSString (const wchar_t * Str)
{
if(!Str) {
    return nil;
}

    NSString *  str;    ///< String in NSString.
#if CP_SIZEOFWCHAR == 4
    str     = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: (CVPtr) Str
                                length: sizeof(wchar_t)* wcslen(Str)
                                encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
                                //encoding: NSUTF32StringEncoding];
#else

    str     = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: (CVPtr) Str
                                length: sizeof(wchar_t)* wcslen(Str);
                                encoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
                                //encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding];
#endif

return str;
}

class File {
public:
  int Open(char * fname, int mode)
  {
    fd = open(fname,  mode);

 }

  int Close()
  {
     close(fd);
     //fd = 0; //CAUSE of the PROBLEM
   }

  ~File ()
   {
     //ALERT Display message box about the error.
     ALERT(fd != 0);
   }

private:
 int fd;

};
```

This is the code to show the message box.

Code to get NSString from wchar_t * string (Wide string) is perfectly fine and was tested. It is used in many places and running fine.

Same code on the other application (which creates Window first) is running fine.

Problem occurs when the destructor of File is called. Since fd is not 0, it shows message box and cause the problem.

When fd is set to 0, no alert box is displayed for constructor. However, other alert are shown  but no problem occurred.

Is it due fd?

Comment: Presumably `WideToNSString()` is one of your functions?  If so can you post the implementation please?

Comment: Code for WidwToNSString is posted. It is my function and is running fine.

Comment: Sorry that code cannot compile; there is a reference to `pStr` (i.e. `wcslen(pStr)`), which is undefined.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I had to change the name, but missed. Now it is corrected.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code; the problem must be elsewhere...

Comment: Are any of these functions in the call stack when the problem occurs? If not, is any of your code in the stack?

Comment: Also, is there any output in the debugger console?

Comment: @PeterHosey: I have added brief code which after fixing the problem is gone.

Comment: @dbasic: How is this file descriptor code related to the message box? There's no code in the question where the two parts interact. Also, you still haven't answered any of my previous questions.

Comment: ALERT calls message box. Since fd is not zeroed, it shows message box. I have given callstack of one of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to say what is causing the exception (please show the code).

I use [`NSRunCriticalAlertPanel()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSRunCriticalAlertPanel) to display fatal errors in my app, which I am able to call pretty much any time I like:

```
void criticalAlertPanel(NSString *title, NSString *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:fmt arguments:va];
    va_end(va);
    NSRunCriticalAlertPanel(title, message, @"OK", nil, nil);
}
```

(this code is ARC enabled).

Comment: When the application is loading, it does some task. Window is created after the loading of application. While loading the application, it calls the code to show the errors (Before creation of Window). Due to this, I got this exception of EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. The function to show alert is similar as you have written.

Comment: @dbasic The alert panel is unrelated to the app window; I am able to display errors any time I like (both before and after windows have been displayed).  Please post your code.